# redirect to profile after registering for website using php

Tags: php

I want to send a user to there profile after registering but I get no input file
not sure what I'm doing wrong but I start a session in an els statement not sure if that's write can someone help me out maybe

```
<?php
//  set  database  connection
require("dbconfig.php");  


//  lets  get  our  posts //

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$bn = $_POST['bandname'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$genre = $_POST['genre'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$image = $_FILES['image'];

/// valid  image  types ///

$image_type = array("image/jpg","image/jpeg","image/bmp","image/gif","image/png");


///  folder  that  will  hold the  image

$imagepath = "images/";


$imagepath .= $image["name"];


// move the  file from the tmp  folder to the  image  folder

if (move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $imagepath)){

$foo = `mogrify -quality 92 -scale 500x $imagepath`;    
}   



//  insert  data into mysql 

    $sql = "insert into dbusers (email, password, bandname, state, genre,           description    , image)

                                                                                              values ('$email','$pass','$bn   ','$state','$genre','$description','".$image['name']        . "')";


if (!mysql_query($sql)){

 die('ERROR' . mysql_error());      

      }else {    

      $id=mysqli_insert_id($sql); // Get the associated ID number
                            // Set up a login session
    session_start();
    $_SESSION ['id'       ] = $id;
    $_SESSION ['bandname' ] = $bandname;
    $_SESSION ['password' ] = $password;
    header  ("Location:ympprofile.php?listid=$id");   
}    
?>
```

Comment: check your code is executing in else section if not then check your mysql query

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
header  ("location:ympprofile.php?listid=$id");
```

to

```
header  ("Location:ympprofile.php?listid=$id");
```

The Location property for the header function is capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the inserted row's id like

```
$id=mysqli_insert_id($sql);

then 

header  ("location:ympprofile.php?listid=$id");
```

Comment: I tried that but still nothing I edited the code above but still no input file

Comment: try it:- 
    else(mysql_query($sql))
and if this doesn't work too then plz mention errors in comment